# Determine type of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $$\left(x^{2}+3xy+y^{2}\right)dx = x^{2}dy$$

This straight away looks like an exact DE. But if I multiply across by $\frac{1}{x^2dx}$ I  have: $$1 + \frac{1}{x}y + \frac{1}{x^2}y^{2} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Could this be interpreted as being a Bernoulli equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = q(x)y^n$ where $p(x) = \frac{3}{x}$, $q(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $n = 2$, with the $1$ just being a constant added on? Or am I taking liberties with the definition of a Bernoulli equation?

Comment: This is a non-linear ODE of homogeneous kind. To make it separable, let $y(x)=x\;u(x)$ .

Comment: It's Riccati's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+3xy+y^2}{x^2}$$
is homogeneous ODE. So we take $y=vx \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$\implies v+x\frac{dx}{dx}=1+3v+v^2 \implies x \frac{dv}{dx}=1+v^2+2v$$ $$\implies \int \frac{dv}{(1+v)^2}= \int \frac{dx}{x}
\implies (1+v)^{-1}=-(\ln x+\ln C)$$
$$\implies y=-x\left (\frac{1}{\ln Cx}+1 \right)$$